# Where to insert comma(s)?

Tags: orthography, conjunctions, commas, parentheses, clauses

Compare these:

> 1. She tried, and, as expected, failed.
> 2. She tried, and as expected, failed.
> 3. She tried and, as expected, failed.
> 4. She tried and as expected, failed.
> 5. She tried and (as expected) failed.

The first seems most correct, while the last seems most elegant. Is it all a matter of taste/style?

I'm also curious of these:

> 6. She tried, and failed.
>    7. She tried and failed.

Is there ever a need for the first form?

Answer (score 6):

I usually follow [Strunk & White](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html) and only deviate from their rules if strict adherence would result in something that breaks the flow of reading/thought.

> - Enclose parenthetic expressions between commas.
> - Place a comma before and or but introducing an independent clause.
> - Do not join independent clauses by a comma.

This points to number 3 being the correct sentence. As for the last two, I definitely prefer number 7 as well. However:

```
She tried, and she failed.
```

And finally

```
She tried; she failed.
```

As commonplace as it may sound, I would add: never judge any sentence as it stands by itself. Depending on the mood and style you want to set, anything might be OK in the right context.

Answer (score 3):

I'm always struggling with over-comma-fication, meaning my own inclination to put in too many. [en- and em-dashes are one (lazy) way around this proclivity, as is paying close attention to how the expository pieces in *The New Yorker* are punctuated.]

I'd choose sentence #3 in your first sampling. It segregates "as expected" (which is incidental to the main event) but otherwise keeps *tried* and *and* together, drawing the reader forward and so letting the sentence flow.

By the same token, I think sentence #7 in the second set is preferable. It's a straight-forward exposition wherein the comma's extraneous. If you really wanted to build up tension, use ellipses or an en-dash -before or after the "and"- to signal as much instead.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to example 6, the comma would be more appropriate if the next word was "but":

> She tried, but failed.

In your example "She tried and failed", if the sentence continues after the "and failed" you very often see parentheses around the "and failed" also:

> She tried (and failed) to...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the style, complexity, mood/insinuation/stress and standard of the whole thing. My use (colloquially, semi-formal and formal) would be 2 or 5 or 2 without the second comma.

Same with the second choice, it depends if you are insinuating/stressing that she was expected to try, or expected to fail, or it is just noted.